# the closure of the set $\{ e^{in\theta}:n\;\text{non-negative integer numbers} \}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

May I ask a question about the closure of the set $\{ e^{in\theta}:n\;\text{non-negative integer numbers} \}$, where $\theta\in\mathbb R$.

Many thanks.

Comment: What is the question? The world must know! In all seriousness, are you asking what the closure to that set is? Can you give us more details on your intuition on the problem, or what you have already tried?

Comment: when $\theta$ is in Q, the question is  easy.

Answer (score 0):

If $\theta=\frac p q \pi$, then the set itself is already closed (and finite) and thus the closure is just the set itself.

Otherwise the closure is the entire unit circle.

Proof is left as an exercise.

Comment: Could you give the detail for the line "Proof is left as an exercise"? I feel it is not easy